# use jquery to get selected value to colomuns from multiple dropdown lists from a table in php

Tags: javascript, php

Please how do i get all the drop down list in the table to auto-complete in the required field, but with my current code it only works for the first row in the table. Kindly assist.

[Image of an idea of what i meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Lk1.png)

below is my code

[drop down code that the j query relies on to get value to columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvOFJ.png)

[j query that runs the get value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW89y.png)

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <br></br>

        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <table id="zctb" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                             <th>ITEM NAME</th>
                             <th>ITEM CATEGORY</th>
                             <th>ITEM BRAND</th> 
                             <th>ITEM QUANTITY</th>                        
                              <th>ITEM SERIAL#</th>                           
                              <th>WAYBILL</th>                           
                              <th>S.R.A</th>                           
                              <th>SUPPLIER</th>
                            </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="zctb">



<?php 
$request_date = date("Y-m-d")??''; 
$request_depatment = $_SESSION['Departnam']??'';


$sql = " SELECT * from  requestitem WHERE request_NUMBER = '$requestNo' " ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{     

  $requestitem=  $result->requestitem_item??'';
  $requestitemDept = ($result->requestitem_department)??'';



                          $query1= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT * from items WHERE items_Name='$requestitem'");
                          $query1->execute();
                              while ($row = $query1->fetch()){
                                 $srlno = $row['SERIAL_NUMBER']?? '';
                                 $itmwybl = $row['items_waybill_no']?? '';
                                 $itmsplyno = $row['supplier_NUMBER']?? '';
                                 $itmbrnd = $row['items_brand']?? '';
                                 $itmsra = $row['items_SRA']?? '';



  ?>


            <tr>
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemname[]" id="itemname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_item);?>" ></td>
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemcategory[]" id="itemcategory" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_category);?>" ></td>         
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itembrand[]" id="itembrand" value="" ></td>         
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemquality[]" id="itemquality" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_no);?>" ></td>
         <td><select name="itemserialno" id="itemserialno" required>
                    <option>Select Name</option>
                          <?php
                                echo "<option value='$srlno' data-itmswybill='$itmwybl' data-itmsupply='$itmsplyno' data-itmbrnd='$itmbrnd' data-itmsra='$itmsra'>".$srlno."</option>";
                             ?>
          </select></td>                  
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemswybill[]" id="itemswybill" value="" ></td>   
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsra[]" id="itemsra" value="" ></td>        
         <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsupply[]" id="itemsupply" value="" ></td>  
                    </tr>
                    <?php $cnt=$cnt+1; } } ?>
                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>

<br>
<div class="form-group">

<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">View Rquistition Form</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<td><a href="view-uploaded-requisition.php?requisition_id=<?= $result->request_NUMBER?>"> <?php echo "<img src='../image/icon/icon-attachment.png' height='80' width='70 class='img-thumbnail'>"; ?> </a></td>
</div>

</div>
<?php } ?>
</br>

                            <button style="font-size:20px" class="btn btn-primary" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp; <a href="view-requestitem.php?requestitem_department=<?php echo $requestitemDept ?>"> Back to Issue Item </a></button>       

                           <button style="font-size:20px" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>&nbsp; Issue Item</button>
         
                           <button style="font-size:20px" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" type="reset" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; cancil Entry</button>
         
                     </form>
                  </div>
              </div>               
          </div>
        </div>     
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#itemserialno').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    $("#itemswybill").val( selectedOption.data('itmswybill') );
    $("#itemsupply").val( selectedOption.data('itmsupply') );
    $("#itembrand").val( selectedOption.data('itmbrnd') );
    $("#itemsra").val( selectedOption.data('itmsra') );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are lot of errors in your code.

1. HTML page should have only one unique id. You are looping through an array and generating html element with same ids **itemname**, **itemcategory**, **itembrand**, **itemquality**, **itemserialno**, **itemswybill**, **itemsra**, **itemsupply**. In each iteration all these ids are created again and again. You could use class instead.
2. Same as above. id **zctb** is given to table as well as tbody.
3. class attribute should appear only once on an element. Your three buttons have it two times.
4. </br> is not valid html tag. It should be <br/>

Now coming to the jquery solution.

You are attaching change handler on select and replacing the element by targeting them with ids. Now all elements are having same ids hence jquery is replacing values for only first set of elements. You need to change your jquery code to below.

Here once change handler is triggered we are finding parent tr element and then finding all the related field to replace with the help of that tr.

```
$('.itemserialno').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    var target = $(this).closest('tr');
    target.find('.itemswybill').val( selectedOption.data('itmswybill') );
    target.find('.itemsupply').val( selectedOption.data('itmsupply') );
    target.find('.itembrand').val( selectedOption.data('itmbrnd') );
    target.find('.itemsra').val( selectedOption.data('itmsra') );
});
```

I have removed php code and added dummy values and created this working version. Hope this helps.

```js
$('.itemserialno').change(function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    var target = $(this).closest('tr');
    target.find('.itemswybill').val( selectedOption.data('itmswybill') );
    target.find('.itemsupply').val( selectedOption.data('itmsupply') );
    target.find('.itembrand').val( selectedOption.data('itmbrnd') );
    target.find('.itemsra').val( selectedOption.data('itmsra') );
});
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <br><br>

  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="zctb" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ITEM NAME</th>
          <th>ITEM CATEGORY</th>
          <th>ITEM BRAND</th>
          <th>ITEM QUANTITY</th>
          <th>ITEM SERIAL#</th>
          <th>WAYBILL</th>
          <th>S.R.A</th>
          <th>SUPPLIER</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemname[]" class="itemname" value="itemname1"></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemcategory[]" class="itemcategory" value="itemcat1"></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itembrand[]" class="itembrand" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemquality[]" class="itemquality" value="itemquality1"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="itemserialno[]" class="itemserialno" required>
              <option>Select Name</option>
              <option value='srlno1' data-itmswybill='itmwybl1' data-itmsupply='itmsplyno1' data-itmbrnd='itmbrnd1' data-itmsra='itmsra1'>srlno1</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemswybill[]" class="itemswybill" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsra[]" class="itemsra" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsupply[]" class="itemsupply" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemname[]" class="itemname" value="itemname2"></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemcategory[]" class="itemcategory" value="itemcat2"></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itembrand[]" class="itembrand" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemquality[]" class="itemquality" value="itemquality2"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="itemserialno[]" class="itemserialno" required>
              <option>Select Name</option>
              <option value='srlno2' data-itmswybill='itmwybl2' data-itmsupply='itmsplyno2' data-itmbrnd='itmbrnd2' data-itmsra='itmsra2'>srlno2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemswybill[]" class="itemswybill" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsra[]" class="itemsra" value=""></td>
          <td><input style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="itemsupply[]" class="itemsupply" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">View Rquistition Form</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <td><a href="view-uploaded-requisition.php">Test</a></td>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <button style="font-size:20px" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp; <a href="view-requestitem.php"> Back to Issue Item </a></button>

  <button style="font-size:20px" name="submit" type="submit" class=" btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>&nbsp; Issue Item</button>

  <button style="font-size:20px" name="submit" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; cancil Entry</button>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the contribution and Clarification, if worked, i will want to ask if i could learn more from you, cause until now there a lot i didn't know in the codes i write.

Comment: please i would be happy if i can get in touch with you personally